# reducing number of choices

Tags: python, web2py

I have two tables:

```
db.define_table('tests', Field('name'), Field('status'),...)
db.tests.status.requires=IS_IN_SET(['OK','obsolete'])
db.define_table('testruns', Field('name'), Field('test', db.tests), ...)
```

My form looks lik this:

```
form = SQLFORM(db.testruns)
```

How can I change the form, that it contains only the tests that have the state 'OK'?

Answer (score 1):

When you define a reference field like `Field('test', db.tests)`, it gets a default `IS_IN_DB` validator, which gives it a default select widget in forms. The `IS_IN_DB` validator defaults to all records in the referenced field, but you can explicitly specify your own `IS_IN_DB` validator and pass in a DAL Set object that limits the records to a subset (in this case, those with tests.status == 'OK'):

```
db.define_table('testruns',
    Field('name'),
    Field('test', db.tests,
          requires=IS_IN_DB(db(db.tests.status == 'OK'), 'tests.id', '%(name)s'),
          represent=lambda id, row: db.tests[id].name))
```

Comment: Nice Anthony! How the represent work in this case? Does it access database for each name with this code db.tests[id].name?

Comment: When generating the options for the select widget, I think it will just do a single query. However, when the `represent` attribute is used (e.g., when serializing a set of Rows from the testruns table or displaying a readonly form), I believe it will do a separate db query for each record.